# Differences between "confident" and "self-confident"

Tags: word-usage

What are the differences between  "confident" and "self-confident" since they both means that some has confidence in themselves?

Answer (score 7):

- You **can** be confident about *someone* or *something else*:

  > I am confident that my son will pass his driving test tomorrow.
- You **can** be confident about *yourself at a particular time* without necessarily being self-confident *in general*:

  > I am confident that I will pass my driving test tomorrow.
- You probably **wouldn't** say *in a general sense*:

  > I am confident.
- Though you **might** say:

  > I am a confident person.
- For a **general statement**, you would most likely say:

  > I am self-confident.
- You **can't** say:

  > I am self-confident that I will pass my driving test tomorrow'.
- You also **can't** be *self-confident about someone or something else*:

  > I am self-confident that my son will pass ...'.